# Counting unique items in array. (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, ios8, xcode6

How do you count the amount of unique items in an Array?

Example:

```
let array:Array<Int> = [1,3,2,4,6,1,3,2]
```

Count function:
 `array.count` will give 8

but I want to count unique items and this will give 5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [NSSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSSet) to throw away duplicates:

```
let array:Array<Int> = [1,3,2,4,6,1,3,2]
let count = NSSet(array: array).count
println(count)
```

This prints:

> 5

Answer (score 16):

**As of Swift 1.2**, Swift has a native `Set` type.  Use the `Set` constructor to create a set from your array, and then the `count` property will tell you how many unique items you have:

```
let array = [1,3,2,4,6,1,3,2]

let set = Set(array)
print(set.count)  // prints "5"
```

---

**For Swift 1.1** and earlier:

Turn your array into an `NSSet`:

```
let array = [1,3,2,4,6,1,3,2]

let set = NSSet(array: array)
println(set.count)  // prints "5"
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSSet).

---

If you are interested in how many of each item you have, you can use a dictionary to count the items:

```
var counts = [Int:Int]()

for item in array {
    counts[item] = (counts[item] ?? 0) + 1
}

print(counts)        // prints "[6: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 1: 2, 4: 1]"
print(counts.count)  // prints "5"
print("There are \(counts[1] ?? 0) ones.")    // prints "There are 2 ones."
print("There are \(counts[7] ?? 0) sevens.")  // prints "There are 0 sevens."
```

Answer (score 5):

implement the function
countDistinct(numbers: [Int]) to return the number of distinct elements in
the array.
NSSet documentation for Swift
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsset

```
func countDistinct(numbers: [Int]) -> Int {
    let array:Array<Int> = numbers
    let count = NSSet(array: array).count
    return count
}

print(countDistinct(numbers: [20, 10, 10, 30, 20]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to stick with **pure swift**, a possible solution consists of:

1. sorting the array
2. traversing the and count the number of times an element differs from the previous one

Translated in code:

```
let start: (Int, Int?) = (0, nil)
let count = array.sorted(<).reduce(start) { initial, value in
    (initial.0 + (initial.1 == value ? 0 : 1), value)
}

let uniqueElements = count.0
```

the result is stored in the element 0 of the `count` tuple.

Explanation: the `start` tuple is initialized with `0` and `nil`, and passed as the initial value to the `reduce` method, called on a sorted copy of the array.
At each iteration, a new tuple is returned, containing the current array element and the current counter, increased by one if the current element is different than the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use following generic method for counting unique values inside an array.

```
func countUniques<T: Comparable>(_ array: Array<T>) -> Int {
    let sorted = array.sorted()
    let initial: (T?, Int) = (.none, 0)
    let reduced = sorted.reduce(initial) {
        ($1, $0.0 == $1 ? $0.1 : $0.1 + 1)
    }
    return reduced.1
}
```